# How to iterate through a column in a csv file using CSVhelper library? using: dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic, csvhelper

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0x1S.jpg)

[CSV file in notepad editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv5ZU.jpg)

```
using CsvHelper;

public class csvread
{
   public dynamic APSSValue ;
   public async Task GetMode()
   {
      try 
      {
         FileOpenPicker openpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
         openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");   
         IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream());
         string UserCultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
         CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, culture: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(UserCultureInfo));
         csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
         csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
         while (csv.Read())
         {
            APSSValue = Enumerable.ToList(csv.GetRecord<dynamic>());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried this way shown above but with this I only get the number of columns.
I also tried

```
csv.Read();
APSSValue = Enumerable.ToList(csv.GetRecords<dynamic>());
```

but this gives me the entire data of csv file.

Questions:

- I want to look for the value under the column **(I_APSS_Modus)** Please see the images shared above, It can be 0 or 1 so how can I look for that value if it is 0 or 1 ?

**NOTE:**

- I don't want the values of entire column because all the values in the column would be either 0 or 1. So i just want one value from any row under that column.
- CSV file is not same every time, so the column number for **(I_APSS_Modus)** will vary if the CSV file is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code which put data into a DataTable so you can easily filter with linq.  Below will work with posted csv

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("B_Kurze_Seite", typeof(Boolean));
            dt.Columns.Add("I_Partikeleinfall Reinluft", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("I_Partikeleinfall Rohluft", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("I_APSS_Modus", typeof(int));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            int row = 0;
            string format = "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss:fff";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0 && !line.StartsWith("sep"))
                {
                    if (++row > 1)
                    {
                        string[] splitRow = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        DateTime.ParseExact(splitRow[0],format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        (splitRow[1] == "FALSE")? false : true,
                        int.Parse(splitRow[2]),
                        int.Parse(splitRow[3]),
                        int.Parse(splitRow[4])
                    });
                    }

                }
            }
            List<int> data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("I_APSS_Modus")).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Here is code that will work with generic columns

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            int row = 0;
            string format = "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss:fff";
            string[] columnNames = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if ((line.Length > 0) && !line.StartsWith("sep"))
                {
                    string[] splitRow = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                    if (++row == 1)
                    {
                        columnNames = splitRow;
                        foreach (string col in splitRow)
                        {
                            switch(col)
                            {
                                case "Timestamp":
                                    dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(DateTime));
                                    break;

                                case "I_APSS_Modus":
                                    dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(int));
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
                        {
                            switch (columnNames[i])
                            {
                                case "Timestamp":
                                    newRow["Timestamp"] =  DateTime.ParseExact(splitRow[i], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                    break;

                                case "I_APSS_Modus":
                                     newRow["I_APSS_Modus"] = int.Parse(splitRow[i]);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    newRow[i] = splitRow[i];
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            List<int> data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("I_APSS_Modus")).ToList();
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: cab you suggest what changes needs to made now and i want for generic columns as every csv file have different number of columns but every csv file will have "I_APSS_Modus" for sure which i want to checlk

Comment: Second solution should work.  I made the assumption each CSV also has a timestamp column and parsed the time to a DateTime object.  Also parsed I_APSS_Modus to an integer.  Everything else I left as a string.

Comment: Its working fine now. Thank you. have a nice day :)

Comment: I do not like CsvHelper because you can do same in c# with a few lines of code (why add an necessary library) and have a lot more flexibility in c# to customize the results.

Comment: @jdweng - I agree CsvHelper can often be overkill. In this case, I would argue it might make sense.  You are also using another library, namely with DataTable. It is taking you about 20 lines of code vs 4 lines of code for the same result that I have in the second part of my answer (taking out the date formatting).  It is also easier to read.

Comment: I'm parsing all the data into the correct datatypes , handling the blank rows, handling the row that starts with sep.  Make sure you are comparing apples and apples.

Comment: You have a definite point.  I am not handling datatypes.  You, however, are not handling csv issues like having a line break in the middle of a field or a double quote in the middle of a field or having the separator ; in the middle of the field.

Comment: Also, handling datatypes was not really the question, since the only column we could be certain of being in each file was I_APSS_Modus.

Comment: What about timestamp?

Comment: Sorry.  I think that was just a comment on my answer: "other files have will be having more number of columns [but every file will have I_APSS_Modus whose value i want]".  If he does need Timestamp as a DateTime, I would say it would be just as easy to parse the string as needed, which is what he would have to do for any other columns you have that he doesn't know the type up front.

Comment: I believe your code will fail if a field has a line break "I have a \n line break", an escaped double quote "I have an \"\" escaped double quote" or a delimiter in the field "I have a ; delimiter".  I'm not sure it is even going to work if the fields are contained in double quotes.  All of which is valid csv.

Comment: We are not talking about ALL CSV.  Just what the OP normally gets.  Why do extra processing for something that never occurs.

Comment: He told you there are going to be different files with different columns.  How do you know one of them won't have those in it?  Why wait for it to break when you can be sure to process ALL valid CSV from the start?

Comment: How do you know it won't change?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the csv specification.  Since [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) has a Copyright of 2005, I don't see it changing.  And if it did, I'd mention it to Josh Close and have him update CsvHelper.

Comment: It is an option and is not needed for this application.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you put `if (++row > 1)` in its own conditional statement rather than just adding it onto the combined statement immediately above it?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the datatable here will include all the last three rows together as a single column value (wrapped in a set of parentheses as part of the value) because you wrapped them in a set of parentheses in your first code block. I'm not sure if that was intentional, but it certainly leads to unexpected output that differs from the input. It seems like a mistake.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons for the separate IF statement 1) I wanted to skip any rows before the header row 2) Wanted to apply only for header row  I think you are wrong about combining rows.  Each column is defined as a INT and if the more than one piece of data is in a column there would be an error because the type would not be an INT.  The code is using dt.Rows.Add(array) which adds one row to the datatable where the array is an array of columns that matches the types defined in the table sequentially.

Comment: My question was not why you had the third if condition, but rather why it was on its own line. Given there is no code in the outer if condition that's not also in the inner if condition, there is no difference I can tell between `if (line.Length > 0 && !line.StartsWith("sep")) { if (++row > 1) {` and `if (line.Length > 0 && !line.StartsWith("sep") && (++row > 1)) {`. Furthermore if you know there will always be a `sep` on the first line, you can just do away with one of those checks, and just write `if (line.Length > 0 && ++row > 1)`. Or better yet, just say `row > 1` and iterate w/in the loop

Comment: Iterating a counter _within a condition check_ seems like a pretty strong code smell to me.

Comment: Your code will increase row when there is a blank line.  My code does not increase row when there is a blank like.  So my code looks for the header row which starts with "sep" and ignores all rows until the header is found.  Your code row is incremented which is not what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with CsvHelper, a simple mapping should do the trick:

```
// Data model of a row (only I_APSS_Modul is of interest)
public class DataSet
{
    public int ApssModus { get; set; }
}

// Mapping
public class ApssMap : ClassMap<DataSet>
{
    public ApssMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ApssModus).Name("I_APSS_Modus");
    }
}

// Reading records
public void GetMode()
{
    
    string UserCultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;

    using (var tr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("any.csv", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(tr, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(UserCultureInfo))
        {
            Delimiter = ";"
        }))
        {

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ApssMap>();
            var records = csv.GetRecords<DataSet>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Check the official docs for all the mapping options: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps

Comment: Hi, simple mapping is not possible as i stated in the NOTE section the data is not same all the time so the number of columns changes [Note: I_APSS_Modus will always be present in the data]. Hence i cannot create a specific mapping class with a specific no. of dataset.

Comment: Ok, i got you wrong then. First you said, you want the values under I_APSS_Modus (which will be returned using the mapping - no matter if there are more columns in the file). But in the NOTE-section you say you don't want the entire column. Could you please explain what you mean by "So i just want one value from any row under that column." - maybe with a an example based on the data from the screenshot?

Comment: I want any value from under column number 5. which is I_APSS_Modus. (5,5) (5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9) (5,10) (5,11) (5,12) example: (5,11) of which '5' is column number and '11' is row number. But remember in this case I_APSS_Modus falls under column number 5 in other file it maybe in other column so there is the issue. and also if you see my other image file my csv file is not having a header file directly it is having a other data at first line "sep=;" so i cant read header directly

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the first row of data, you have to read the header first and then you can read the first data row.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Timestamp;B_Kurze_Seite;I_Parikeleinfall Reinluft;I_Partikeleinfall Rohluft;I_APSS_Modus");
        writer.WriteLine("2020 06 27 08:49:20:335;FALSE;15;0;0");
        writer.WriteLine("2020 06 27 08:49:20:391;FALSE;0;0;0");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        csv.Read();
        var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>();

        var APSSModus = record.I_APSS_Modus;
    }
}
```

Edit: This should give you the same answer as @jdweng

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("sep=;");
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine("Timestamp;B_Kurze_Seite;I_Parikeleinfall Reinluft;I_Partikeleinfall Rohluft;I_APSS_Modus");
        writer.WriteLine("2020 06 27 08:49:20:335;FALSE;15;0;0");
        writer.WriteLine("2020 06 27 08:49:20:391;FALSE;0;0;0");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

        csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row[0].StartsWith("sep=") || row.All(string.IsNullOrEmpty);

        var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();

        List<int> data = records.Select(x => (int)int.Parse(x.I_APSS_Modus)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what i gave in the image file is just an example the original csv file is having around 9000 entries.

Comment: If all you want is the value of "one" of the I_APSS_Modus values, then this should work if it is 9 records or 9000 records.  But maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Just in case you still wanted to use CsvHelper, I added an answer that should give you the same results as @jdweng.

Comment: By the way will this also work if the number of column changes .. because what i gave is just one example other files have will be having more number of columns [but every file will have I_APSS_Modus whose value i want] ..

Comment: Yes, it works as long as one column is named I_APSS_Modus.